# IdentityServer 4, OpenIdConnect redirect to external sign-in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am trying to build multiple small ASP.Net core Mvc services that connect to a Identity server built using IdentityServer4.

I have setup the OpenIdOption on the MVC services that looks like  this

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

where `http://localhost:5000` is the endpoint on which my Identity server is running. say if my MVC server is at `http://localhost:5002` I see that when I set a `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller, it redirects to my identity server and if the check fails, it looks for the signin page back at `http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc`

Now the issue I have is that I wan the login page to be hosted by my `Identity Server` hosted at `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` so that all the MVC services just make use of this to get user identity, but unfortunately I am unable to see how to set this `RedirectUrl`.

[image]

*I know the diagram is inaccurate in how it works with reference to the flow, just trying to simplify what I want to accomplish :)*

is it possible to accomplish this ?

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what that `/signin-oidc` route is for. The general flow works like this:

1. User visits the ASP.NET Core site.
2. App asks the default authentication scheme, `"Cookies"`, to authenticate.

   1. The cookie authentication handler attempts to restore the identity from the (signed) cookie information.
   2. Cookie authentication fails because cookie is missing.
3. App asks the default challenge scheme, `"oidc"`, to perform an authentication challenge.

   1. OpenIdConnect authentication handler redirects to the OpenId Connect authentication provider, this is your Identity Server.
   2. User logs in successfully on the Identity Server.
   3. User is POSTed to `/signin-oidc` which is the remote sign-in address for the OpenId Connect authentication handler.
   4. OpenId Connect authentication middleware handles the `/signin-oidc` route and retrieves the user information from the sign-in request that was made by Identity Server.
   5. OpenId Connect authentication scheme creates the authentication ticket and asks the configured sign-in scheme to sign in the user.
4. Cookie authentication scheme handles the sign-in process and creates the user identity. It stores the identity in a cookie, so it can be retrieved on future requests without having to go through the whole authentication challenge pipeline again.
5. User is signed in.

So the `/signin-oidc` endpoint is the way to return back to your application to *complete* the sign-in process of the OpenId Connect authentication flow. By the time the user reaches this address, they have already signed in on the Identity Server and they are being redirected back to the application to continue where they originally left off.

Usually, the time the user spends on that route is minimal since it will redirect back into a “proper” application route immediately after the sign-in request has been processed.

So no, there will be no login form here. The login process itself is the responsibility of your OpenId Connect authentication provider, your Identity Server. That’s the whole point about this, so you e.g. login securely on `google.com` with your Google credentials instead of on `my-random-and-probably-untrusted-app.example.com` which definitely should not get hold of your actual Google credentials.

Comment: Thanks!! this really saved my day. I got confused with the `RedirectUris` on the Identity server's client attribute. when this was not correct I didn't see the login pages, so I assumed that this was a call back.

Comment: How should I handle the situation where the .NET Core app has an external FQDN and an internal FQDN? signin-oidc attemps to call both which is causing a problem in our application.

Comment: @JoshMonreal What do you mean with “attempts to call both”? Usually, when OIDC is challenged, it will redirect to the identity provider (IdP) using a redirect URL that is constructed relatively to where the original request came from. So if you go to `https://myapp.com`, the redirect URL should be `https://myapp.com/signin-oidc`; when you access the app through `https://myapp.local`, then the redirect URL should be `https://myapp.local/signin-oidc`. So the app itself is (by design) completely oblivious to how it is being hosted.

Comment: So our web application is deployed in Azure App Service on which the URL cannot be accessed from the public internet. Let's call it https://internallink.company.com. In order for end-users to access this web application outside the company network we created an external FQDN (alias) for it, say, https://externallink.company.com.

Now, when I run the web application using OIDC it checks both links: https://internallink.com/signin-oidc and https://externallink.com/signin-oidc. This is the problem that I'm having because it should not call the internal one.

Comment: @JoshMonreal When you say _“it checks both links”_, what exactly do you mean with that? Because the app itself doesn’t open these. This is where a user should be sent after signing in through e.g. AAD. Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63250093/216074) what this is about? Then I’ll look and reply over there.

Comment: Yes, it's about that question. It explains the issue better. Thank you for your help.