# Can't make the authentication work uner .NET Core 2.2 and Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

This question will be bounted in two days but I need help prior to that.

I'm running two projects in the same solution. One is my ID provider (I'm using IDS4) while the other is just a simple MVC client (with two methods on the controller - *Home/Open* and *Home/Secured*. The latter is decorated by the attribute *Authorize*.

When I try to access the open one, it behaves as supposed to. The secured one, however, throws a 401 at me **but** doesn't get sent back to a login page. I'm fairly sure that I missed something essential in the setup of the client or of the server.

On the **ID provider side** I have the following.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiResources)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients)
    .AddTestUsers(Users)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityResources);

  services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(_ =>
    {
      _.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
      _.Audience = "http://localhost:5001";
    });
}

public IEnumerable<Client> Clients => new[]
{
  new Client
  {
    ClientId = "MvcClient",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MvcSecret".Sha256(), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)) },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    }
  }
};
```

I've verified that entering manually *http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc/*, I get to see the *index.html* document located there. I was expecting that when I attempt to access the secured page, I'd get hit on there. Instead, I'm only getting a simple 401.

On the **MVC client side** I have the following.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(_ =>
    {
      _.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
      _.Audience = "http://localhost:5002";
      _.SaveToken = true;
      _.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      _.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = true };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(_ => { _.ClientId = "mvc_client"; });
}
```

I need to figure out why it doesn't send me to the login page as specified. I also need to come up with a way to login and authenticate using JWT under MVC. I'm thankful if I at least get a suggestion on how to trouble-shoot it and/or comparison to the correct behavior. A working example would be great to have too.

I've been researching it for days and my opinion is that the official guide is unclear, starts to become outdated and, which is the most confusing part, jumps a bit between topics without a red thread. All the examples and blogs I've seen (and I've seen a lot) won't work on my machine or turn out to be invalid for the latest version of .NET Core (which at the moment is 2.2). The [closest one](https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa) didn't really run neither and I suspect that there's no point investing time trouble-shooting it.

Comment: Can we see this class IdServerConfiguration?

Comment: @eVolve Not sure what you mean, mate. The first sample is in the configuration class for the project that runs my Identity Server, if that's what you're asking. Please explain if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: In your code you call this     .AddInMemoryClients(IdServerConfiguration.Clients) yet the way the code is displayed here the clients look to be in the startup class.

Comment: @eVolve Ah, sorry about the confusion. I was trying my best to make the code informative but brief. The class *IdServerConfiguration* is just a convenience class storing the client definitions. It's the same as if the client definition was shoved directly into the method *AddInMemoryClients(new[]{new Client{...}})*.

Comment: @eVolve I updated the source code to be more clear on the thing that made you ask.

Comment: Not sure what ports you are using for what projects, but all of the IDS4 examples use 5000 for the IDS4 implementation.  I notice in your client config, you have the redirecturi pointing to localhost:5000/signin-oidc.   Is 5000 your IDS4 port, or the port for your MVC app?   It should be pointing to the port for your MVC app.   Also, the QuickStart examples from IDS4 use the implicit grant type for MVC.  Your config is using Hybrid.   Might also be related to your issue.

Comment: @user1011627 Aha, mabe we're onto something here. Just to be as clear as possible. The *RedirectUris* that was set to *localhost:5000/signin-oidc* (5000 is my IDS4 port) is now set to *localhost:5002/home/login* (5002 is my MVC app port). I.e. I'm using controller *Home* and method *LogIn* instead of a static *index.html* file in directory called *signin-oidc*. Is that correct? (I'm not sure what's the convention I have to type in exactly and what's just a name that I can set myself as I wish. As for the *implicit*, I thought it was for SPAs only but I've tried with it too. Same issue then.

Comment: Your RedirectUri should be set to "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc".    PostLogoutRedirectUri should be set to "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc".   The routes to these uris are managed by the OIDC middleware and are expected to be in that format.  If you want to change them, you have to specify the URL in the CallBackPath in the OIDC options when you are configuring it.

Comment: Since you didn't show some of the configuration that is required, I have to assume you have it all wired up properly.   Things that I don't see that are required:

1)  MVC Startup.cs must have a call to UseAuthentication in Configure method.

2)  IDS4 Startup.cs must have a call to UseIdentityServer in Configure method.

Comment: do you still need help ?

Comment: @MohamedElrashid Yes, I still do. I was in the hospital for a while and couldn't fight the issue. Sorry about that. Did you have an insight on my issue or perhaps a question for elaboration on a detail?

Comment: @user1011627 Sorry for the silence - unscheduled visit at the hospital. I'd like to confirm three things about your elaboration on *RedirectUri*. (1) When you say *RedirectUri*, you mean this, right: *RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"}*? (2) I have no controller/action configured on that endpoint in my MVC application. Do I have to implement a page at that address? E.g. a static page named *localhost:5002/signin-oidc/index.html* or perhaps something with *[HttpGet("signin-oidc]*. (3) Does is have to be verbatim "*.../signin-oidc*" or can I set it to *.../security/login*?

Comment: 1)  Correct
2)  No, the signin-oidc route is handled by the middleware.
3)  It is my understanding that you can change it, but I have not so I can't give guidance on that part.

Here is a good explanation on another Q/A.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458612/identityserver-4-openidconnect-redirect-to-external-sign-in-url

Comment: @user1011627 I suspect that there's something more that's wrong with my setup. I realized that I should be able to access the login page on the ID server but when I go to *localhost:5000/connect/authorize* I get nothing. Or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: Can you navigate to the well known configuration of IDS?

Comment: @user1011627 Yes, I get a listing that **to me** looks as supposed to. Including the line with authorization endpont. Klicking there leads me to no page, though.