# signin-oidc Also Tries to Call Internal FQDN

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

We have an ASP.NET Core application that uses the OpenId Connect authentication protocol. In Azure AD B2C we setup the external FQDN (domain alias) (https://externallink.company.com) as the redirect URI. What we noticed is that after redirecting to https://externallink.company.com/signin-oidc it then redirects to the internal FQDN https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc which is the URL of the App Service in Azure. The internal link is not accessible outside the company's network and should stay that way.

[image]

The error that we got is this:

redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 'https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx'.%0D%0ACorrelation ID

This is how we have setup the authentication in the Startup class.

[image]

Should I specifically put the Callback path so that OpenId does not attempt to call the internal FQDN?

Update:

If I try to add the internal FQDN in the list of redirect URIs I will be able to sign in but afterwards I will get this error (URL is https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc). This is expected because as I've mentioned the internal URL cannot be accessed via the public internet.

[image]

Update 2:

Based from the logs of WAF it does not redirect to https://internallink.com/signin-oidc. After authenticating it goes to https://externallink.com/api/foo which is the desired outcome.
[image]

Comment: _“What we noticed is that after redirecting to https://externallink.company.com/signin-oidc it then redirects to the internal FQDN https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc”_ – So the externallink/signin-oidc actually _redirects_ (with a status 30x) to the internal URL? Are you sure about that? Can you include a screenshot from the browser that makes this clear?

Comment: @poke: Now that you've said it, I checked and it didn't. Before authenticating it attempts to go to https://externallink.company.com/foo which is protected by the Authorize attribute. B2C page pops up, I sign in then the error happens.

Comment: So the `Location` header of the 302 redirect contains the redirect URL to `internallink.company.com/signin-oidc`? Then this appears to be simply that the application does not know that it is being hosted under externallink.com. So you should adjust the reverse proxy or whatever is in front of the web app to set the `Host` header correctly when forwarding the request to the app.

Comment: I think I understand where the problem is coming from. The web application is hosted in Azure App service with URL of https://internallink.company.com, therefore, it makes sense that the redirect URI set by the application is https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc. The external link is the domain alias of the internal link so that end-users will be able to access the application. 

Since https://internallink.company.com cannot be accessed via the public internet, the web browser is not able to go to https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc.

Comment: Okay, yeah, then you will probably need to configure the app service to also accept the external URL properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was able to solve this problem on my own. I just have to set the `ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri` under the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event to the external FQDN.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { ... })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
       ...

       options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => 
       {
           context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://externallink.com/signin-oidc";
           return Task.FromResult(0);
       };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register in Azure AD the exact redirect URL to use and it should match the redirect URL you sent to Azure AD.

It's a security feature to restrict the allowed redirect-url. Accepting any URL would introduce a major security vulnerability.

Comment: But that's where the problem comes in. If I register the internal URL as a redirect URI in B2C I would be able to sign in but afterwards I will get to a proxy error page because the internal URL is an internal zone and cannot be accessed via the public internet. 

This was the reason of having the external FQDN in the first place, for users to be able to login to the application using the alias.

Comment: the redirect URL does not need to be reachable from the internet or from B2C, only from your web-browser. The redirect is acheived using an auto-submitted HTML-form. I havent used B2C but this is how openID-connect works.

Comment: Exactly, and my browser is using a public internet (i.e. our home network) to access the internal link. And it will not work because our home network will attempt to call https://internallink.company.com/signin-oidc which is only accessible inside the company's network.

The main problem is why OpenId connect calls both the external and internal FQDNs when using signin-oidc. My expectation is that it should only use the external one.